# What is the difference between the verbs "shore up" and "prop up"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, difference, usage, word-difference

According to the Oxford dictionary the verb "shore up" means, support or hold up something with props or beams. However this acceptation can be expressed with "prop up". So I struggle to grasp the slightest of difference between these verbs.

I know that "shore up" may be used figuratively to say give support to anything that would otherwise fail or decline. So apparently shore up has a larger meaning. I want to know the context where either of these verbs is used.

example: shore up a building  vs  prop up a building  (what is the difference)

Comment: Some example sentences would be helpful to define your issue better. Both terms have other meanings.

Comment: *Shore up* suggests *reinforce*; there is already some support, and the beams, etc. add to it. *Prop up* suggests that the props are the only support.

Answer (score 3):

> shoring up *something*

is to reinforce the base for better support

[image]

> propping up is one method of shoring up *something*

[image]

using "props" or beams.  One can also

> prop open a door

[image]